# AWS S3 Policy wildcard ("*") works, but "s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject", etc does not

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

By following the example here [Uploading Photos to Amazon S3 from a Browser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html) I am able to upload files from my browser to my S3 bucket.  However, when I attempt to modify the policy to be more specific by addeing the following statement I get an access denied error:

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
             "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}*"
        ]
    }
```

However, the following statement does allow me to upload to the bucket:

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
           "*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3::[MY_BUCKET]/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}*"
        ]
    }
```

I am logging in my user using federated login and placing them into an AWS Identity pool.  The policy containing the above code is assumed by the Authenticated role of my Identity pool.  I've confirmed that this Identity ID exists in my Identity pool.  All my research tells me that I should be able to be more specific with my actions so I have no idea what is going wrong here.

**Edit:**

I realized it might be useful to know how the files got in the bucket in the first place.  I'm using the aws-sdk from npm and the following code to upload image files to the bucket:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const fileName = userId + '/' + utilities.getGUID();
        s3.upload({
            Key: fileName,
            Body: file,
            ACL: 'public-read'
        }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                dropzoneUtilities.setDropzoneFileCanceled(file);
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                dropzoneUtilities.setDropzoneFileComplete(file);
                dropzoneUtilities.removeFile(file);
                resolve({ data, name: file.name});
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this in your upload code:

```
ACL: 'public-read'
```

The documentation is not unambiguous on this point, but including this requires the `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html#using-with-s3-actions-related-to-objects

Comment: Adding the "s3:PutObjectAcl" did the trick.  Thank you.  I picked up the "public-read" from one of Amazon's AWS examples.  Unfortunately, I still haven't found good documentation on what it means, especially as it relates to the "authenticated-read" option.  Are there any issues with public read?  Anything I've uploaded using "authenticated-read' rs" results in access denied.

Comment: `public-read` means anybody knowing the URL can download the object -- the object is public, requires no authentication to download.  If you want the objects downloadable by anybody, this is the option you want.

Comment: Is this also the permission I should have if I only want logins associated with my Cognito Identity Pool to be able to view and download files in the bucket?  It doesn't seem like that should be the case.

Comment: No, this makes the object downloadable by anyone.